# How to set each char of a string to a different TextView in a loop

Tags: java, android, for-loop, char, textview

I already declarde all the Objects, and read a few threads on SO. Afterwards i tried to set up an array but without any success. Furthermore my concern is, that when i put all the TextViews in an Array they don't work anymore with the whole design of the app.

I think that my last try is the closest to a solution!

Example (but withouth typing imgBeer 5 times):

```
if(calc.getBeerCount()<100000){
    String convert = Integer.toString(calc.getBeerCount());
    for(int i = 0; i < convert.lenght(); i++){ //edited
        imgBeer1.setText(convert.charAt(i));
        imgBeer2.setText(convert.charAt(i));
        imgBeer3.setText(convert.charAt(i));
        imgBeer4.setText(convert.charAt(i));
        imgBeer5.setText(convert.charAt(i));
    }

}else{
    txtAlcLvl.setText("For sure! Do you coun't annually?");
}
```

Thats what i tried so far:

```
if(calc.getBeerCount()<100000){
    String convert = Integer.toString(calc.getBeerCount());
    for(int i = 0; i < convert.lenght(); i++){ //edited
        String test = "imgBeer" + i;
        test.setText(convert.charAt(i));
    }

}else{
    txtAlcLvl.setText("For sure! Do you coun't annually?");
}
```

for sure this didn't work but i can't figure out how it should. How should the array looks like?

**and i tried this as well where 'findViewById' is marked red.
'can't resolve method 'findViewById(int)'' is the shown comment:**

```
if(calc.getBeerCount()<100000){
    String convert = Integer.toString(calc.getBeerCount());
    for(int i = 0; i < convert.lenght(); i++){ //edited
        ((TextView)findViewById(textViewIds[i])).setText(convert.charAt(i));

    }

}else{
    txtAlcLvl.setText("For sure! Do you coun't annually?");
}
```

Comment: So potentially your going to loop up to 100,000 times? do you have 100,000 textviews?!? You only need to loop the `convert.length()`

Comment: @Mark Kenn, you're right, that was not what i wanted to do. I Changed the sections and marked it with //edited I just want to put all of the 5 chars possible of the int from getBeerCount() in separat TextViews

Comment: You need to look at Context.getResources().getIdentifier() if you want to use dynamic TextView names like that. Furthermore, if you are planning on dynamically adding these text views and having them in a scroll view (the only way I can imagine that many TextViews) you are better off looking at RecyclerView's and Adapters.

Comment: I allready have set up all the TextViews in the xml, i can't just change it now. I'm a bit confused isn't there just a way to adress several TextViews with ascending numbers? imgBeer + i or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure id out finally =)

in The Fragment Class i instantiate an ArrayList & the Methode who set the TextView text:

```
private ArrayList<TextView> test = new ArrayList<>();
public void showConsumption(){

        if(calc.getBeerCount() < 100000) {
            String convert = Integer.toString(calc.getBeerCount());
            for (int i = 0; i < convert.length(); i++) {
                test.get(i).setText(Character.toString(convert.charAt(i)));
            }
        }else{
            txtAlcLvl.setText("For sure! Do you coun't annually?");
        }
    }
}
```

And in the onCreate Methode of the Fragment i put this in:

```
TextView imgBeer1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgBeer1);
TextView imgBeer2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgBeer2);
TextView imgBeer3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgBeer3);
TextView imgBeer4 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgBeer4);
TextView imgBeer5 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgBeer5);

test.add(imgBeer1);
test.add(imgBeer2);
test.add(imgBeer3);
test.add(imgBeer4);
test.add(imgBeer5);
```

Thanks for your Help anyway, obviously my question wasn't asked exactly enough.